# Textile parsing in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, parsing, textile

Are there any libraries to parse Textile (Textile to HTML) which will work in an Objective C iPhone app? C libraries will work too.

**Update:** I couldn't find any sufficiently developed libraries in C/Obj-C, but I did find one written in Javascript, which I used through an invisible UIWebView.

Link: [Javascript textile parser](http://jrm.cc/extras/live-textile-preview.php)

Comment: That link appears to be broken?

Answer (score 1):

The only C library that I could find that might have Textile support is Natacha Porté's [libupskirt](http://git.instinctive.eu/cgit/libupskirt/) library. It is described as being for markdown; however, there is a branch in the git repository called `textile` with a description of "Initial draft of Textile parsing". I have not tried this, so I cannot speak to the functionality, but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I was able to find aside from the other answer given here is one that's written in C++ and uses Qt ( http://github.com/IndigoJo/qijtextile ).  I wouldn't suspect that you could just drop it in, but it might make for a usable template to implement it with Obj-C and/or C.